# Doubly transitive Galois group

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $x$ and $t$ be 2 indeterminates. Suppose $F(x,t)$ in $K(x)[t]$ be irreducible and separable in the variable $t$.

How do I show $F(x,t)$ is doubly transitive over $F(x)$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you clarify what the Galois group of a polynomial in more than one variable is? I don't think I have seen that before.

Comment: What do you mean over $F(x,t)$? That is already a field containing both $x$ and $t$.

Comment: So that is not a polynomial in two variables.