# How to show that, the Galois Group is doubly transitive.

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be any algebraically closed field of characteristic $p\neq 2$.
Let $x,s$ are independent variables.  How to show that Galois group  $G$ of a polynomial $f(x,s)$ is doubly transitive over F(s).

Things I have in hand is 1) $f(x,s)$ is irreducible and separable in the variable $x$.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this just a repost of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2703097/11619)? You do know that we normally edit questions :-)

Comment: Undoubtedly you mean *doubly transitive on the set of zeros of $f$*. I don't think having doubly transitive Galois groups would be any rarer than in the case of extensions over $\Bbb{Q}$, when the Galois group of, say a splitting field of a cubic acts doubly transitively on the roots whenever the discriminant is a non-square. The same should hold here. For splitting fields of higher degree polynomials it's a bit trickier to see.